# Force specflow test failure

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

Is there any way of forcing a Specflow test to fail? I've a test which loops through messages. If it finds the correct message ID I use fluent assertions to confirm the message values are correct. I want to fail the test if the message is not found at all.

Comment: Show us some code and we can help, but perhaps you just need something as simple as `Assert.False(....condition...)`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code its hard to provide the right answer. However, you can select the message based on the expected id, then assert against what you've selected to cause the test to fail. Something like this:

```
      var messageExpected =
        from message in messages
        where message.Id == "123"
        select message;

      messageExpected.Should().NotBeNullOrEmpty("Because you expect to find the message.");
```

Comment: Can you please review my answer to see if this solves your problem?